# Open JSON in JavaScript template (flask)

Tags: javascript, python, json, highcharts, flask

I need make a plot with JavaScript (I use [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/)) and display it using flask. In this template, I need to open a JSON file, but I can't. The flask log doesn't contain any errors. Is it possible that the flask home path is different and doesn't find the file?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script>
$(function() {

$.getJSON({{ url_for('static',filename="datos.json")}}, function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
```

Edit 1: I have this directories structure:

```
app/
    init.py
    templates/
    static/
          datos.json
```

Edit 2: I'm using this [example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) from Highchar. The differences between the example and this code, is where I load JSON the file from (in the example it is from Highchar and in this code from my PC). Looking at the `network chrome dev tools` the jquery-2.0.3.min.map has initiator in the example but not in my code, and the JSON in the example is type text/javascript and in the code application/json.  Could someone explain why?

Comment: And `datos.json` is placed *directly* in the `static` subfolder? What happens when you load `http://localhost:8080/static/datos.json`?

Comment: Just to expand on Martijn's comment; `url_for` get the URI abs path, not the fs path.

Comment: for starters, you could debug this in any tool that gives you a `network` view (chrome dev tools, for instance) to see if the file is actually loaded, and where is it searched.

Comment: If you run console.log(data), inside $.getJSON(), it is empty or you receive any values?

Comment: your link seems to be incorrect...

Comment: In the original code, the end of URL to get a JSON have a `&callback=?` and the first line in the JSON file is a `?`. when JSON file is call the `?` (in the file and URL) change for `jQuery` and a number. In my code don't. I thinks this is the problem. Why?

Comment: ? is used in jsonp, to avoid cross-domain problem.